# SVNKit - Check if Directory exists

Tags: java, svn, repository, versioning, svnkit

So, I've created a project TEST under an SVN repository and I want to know if this project directory exists with SVNKit library. Protocol is http.

I tried for example...

```
  private String urlSviluppo = "http://myrepo/SVILUPPO";


  DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
  SVNURL url = SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(urlSviluppo);

  ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager("user", "pwd");      

  DAVRepository repositorySviluppo = (DAVRepository)DAVRepositoryFactory.create(url, null);
  repositorySviluppo.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

  DefaultSVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
  SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options, "user", "pwd");

  clientManager.createRepository(url, true);
```

how can I access repository/project info ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the example at ["Printing Out a Subversion Repository Tree"](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_A_Subversion_Repository_Tree). It contains the following code:

```
SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repository.checkPath( "" ,  -1 );
if ( nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.NONE ) {
      System.err.println( "There is no entry at '" + url + "'." );
      System.exit( 1 );
} else if ( nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.FILE ) {
      System.err.println( "The entry at '" + url + "' is a file while a directory was expected." );
      System.exit( 1 );
}
```

That checks if your location is ok as a repository root.

```
Collection entries = repository.getDir( path, -1 , null , (Collection) null );
Iterator iterator = entries.iterator( );
while ( iterator.hasNext( ) ) {
     SVNDirEntry entry = ( SVNDirEntry ) iterator.next( );
     ...
```

Iterate over the entries of the current dir.

```
if ( entry.getKind() == SVNNodeKind.DIR ) {
    listEntries( repository, ( path.equals( "" ) ) ? entry.getName( ) : path + "/" + entry.getName( ) );
....
```

Call it recursively for sub-dirs (if you want to visit). This should give you enough material to do the whole function.